# Oracle apex interactive grid export/download excel problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm working on a new application based on oracle Application Express version 20.2, I have an interactive grid that's linked automatically to a table in my oracle database which works fine with no problems, I have a where condition that filters the data based on an item value ex: **WHERE COLUMN1 = :P20_ITEM**  The problem is when i try to use the download option inside the interactive grid to download the data as excel file or html or pdf i get an error: **Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403** but when i try to download it as csv it works with no issues, is it a bug in oracle apex version 20 or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try enabling debug and looking at the debug log

Comment: Already done that, I keep getting the same error message: ORA-01403 not data found

Comment: try adding nvl to the item Ex: NVL(:P20_ITEM, COLUMN1) = COLUMN1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after days of trying to figure out the issue, I found the solution, The issue was that i was using highlights feature in the interactive grid and i noticed when i remove the highlights the export feature works with no issues (pdf, excel, html, csv) and that was it, I think it's some kind of a bug in the interactive grid since i was not modifying anything, it's auto linked to a table in my database and i was using the highlights feature already integrated in the interactive grid, so yeah i removed the highlights and used plain javascript to highlight colors and now it's working as expected.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, but what do I know? Have you tried it on apex.oracle.com?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug, but what do I know?

**Other Thoughts**

1. Have you tried it on apex.oracle.com?
2. The Download feature does a Submit to generate the download report. I wonder if the (presumed) bug is not passing the :P20_ITEM value to your query. Have you tried explicitly submitting that item to session state using a "Execute PL/SQL Code" action?

Comment: 1 - I didn't try it on apex.oracle.com
2 - I removed the entire condition but no success, still the same issue with automatically linked table and no where conditions or whatsoever

Comment: I've had good luck solving a problem by recreating the setup as simply as possible, eliminating as much as possible to isolate the factors. Maybe you can use apex.oracle.com to get there?